# After upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 I get a black screen (ubuntu)

Tags: unity, upgrade, 13.10, screen

After upgrading my 13.04 vm to 13.10 when I run my 13.10 vm all I get is a black screen with flashing _. I can alt f1-f6 to get into tty1-6 and I ran apt-get update & upgrade but still no luck.. When I try to run gui apps from the tty1 it states that GtkWarning: could not open display.

And when I type unity the error says
no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
unity-panel-service: no process found

Can someone help me to get unity working again?

The link you gave me did not fix the problem and since this is virtual machine i dunno which video card it is using

Comment: Could you then give more details? We don't know even what virtual machine you are using, if you don't tell us. Please add more details.

Comment: Please tell us the virtualisation software you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I faced something like that a few times but I never managed to make it work correctly however there is one thing that I didn't try 'sudo do-release-upgrade'.I hope that this helps you.